# How to dynamically create and iterate Json Object inside a Json Array using Postman - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman, http-post

I have a payload like mentioned below :

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters": {
    "batter": [
      {
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
      },
      {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate"
      },
      {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Blueberry"
      },
      {
        "id": "1004",
        "type": "Devil’sFood"
      }
    ]
  },
  "topping": [
    {
      "id": "5001",
      "type": "None"
    },
    {
      "id": "5002",
      "type": "Glazed"
    },
    {
      "id": "5005",
      "type": "Sugar"
    },
    {
      "id": "5007",
      "type": "PowderedSugar"
    },
    {
      "id": "5006",
      "type": "ChocolatewithSprinkles"
    },
    {
      "id": "5003",
      "type": "Chocolate"
    },
    {
      "id": "5004",
      "type": "Maple"
    }
  ]
}
```

**I want to increment the json objects dynamically(it can be a duplicate as well) which is inside the array topping based on the array size. For example if mention the array size as topping[10] it is suppose to create a payload of 10 objects and push those 10 objects of similar type inside the array topping ** Is it possible to dynamically create json objects and post the request in postman??

Kind note : The size of the array should be parameterized. Please let me know.
Please find the image highlighted in green. I want to dynamically increase the payload(topping array size based on the index using postman

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

Tab Pre-request

```
let req = {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "topping": []
};

let numberOfTopping = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfTopping; i++) {
    let toppingItem = {
        "id": `${_.random(5001, 5010)}`,
        "type": `${_.sample(["Glazed", "Sugar", "None"])}`
    };
    req.topping[i] = toppingItem;
}

pm.variables.set("req", JSON.stringify(req));
```

Tab body

[image]

Result

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "topping": [
    {
      "id": "5006",
      "type": "Glazed"
    },
    {
      "id": "5001",
      "type": "Sugar"
    },
    {
      "id": "5006",
      "type": "Glazed"
    },
    {
      "id": "5006",
      "type": "None"
    },
    {
      "id": "5008",
      "type": "Sugar"
    }
  ]
}
```